# could not retrieve field name from database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO project (clientname, salesperson, prospect)
                       VALUES ('$clientName','$salesPer','$prospectVal')");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $projectID = $row['projectid'];


            return $projectID;

        }
```

I am not getting the projectID from the database. The field name is a dynamic one which increments on each insertion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to select items with an INSERT statement. That wont work.

Try this.

```
SELECT projectid, clientname, salesperson, prospect FROM project
```

You could also be looking for the Insert ID, the ID this insert statment got. Then this would work.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO project (clientname, salesperson, prospect)
    VALUES ('$clientName','$salesPer','$prospectVal')");

if($result)
{
     $insert_id = mysql_insert_id();
}
```

3rdly, please look into some input sanitation (it could be that you are sanitizing the values above this snippet but just to be sure. Look at this function.

[`mysql_real_escape_string();`](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me the use of SELECT Statement, i was totally lost somewhere

Answer (score 2):

```
For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
```

Are you looking for [`mysql_insert_id()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)?